# Injectivity multivariable function

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus

Assume we have some function

$$H=\left(\begin{array}{c}g(x_{1},x_{2})\\ c(x_{1},x_{2})\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}\\ x_1x_2\end{array}\right)$$

How to check whether $H$ is injective, assuming that $x_1 \in [0,1]$ $x_2 \in [0,1]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $z \in \mathbb{R}^2$ Following the definition of an injective function we have to check there is only one tuple $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $H((x,y))=z$, if there is one. We can't say a priori if this is possible since we perhaps don't know if the function is surjective.

To show that a function is **not** injective find $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ so that $H((x_1,y_1))=H((x_2,y_2))$, with $(x_1,y_1)≠(x_2,y_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$H(x_2,x_1) = H(x_1,x_2). $$